# Adding characters to the middle of a file without overwriting the existing characters in C

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, system-calls

I am quite rusty with C and system calls and pointers in general, so this is a good refresher exercise to get back on track.  All I need to do is, given a file such as this:

```
YYY.txt: "somerandomcharacters"
```

Change it to be like this:

```
YYY.txt: "somerandomabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzcharacters"
```

So all that is done is some characters added to the middle of the file.  Obviously, this is quite simple, but in C you must keep track and manage the size of the file in advance before adding the additional characters.

Here is my naive try:

```
//(Assume a file called YYY.txt exists and an int YYY is the file descriptor.)
char ToBeInserted[26] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
//Determine the current length of YYY
int LengthOfYYY = lseek(YYY, 0, 2);
if(LengthOfYYY < 0)
  printf("Error upon using lseek to get length of YYY");
//Assume we want to insert at position 900 in YYY.txt, and length of YYY is over 1000.

//1.] Keep track of all characters past position 900 in YYY and store in a char array.
lseek(YYY, 900, 0); //Seeks to position 900 in YYY, so reading begins there.
char NextChar;
char EverythingPast900[LengthOfYYY-900];
int i = 0;
while(i < (LengthOfYYY - 900)) {
    int NextRead = read(YYY, NextChar, 1); //Puts next character from YYY in NextChar
    EverythingPast900[i] = NextChar;  
    i++;
}

//2.] Overwrite what used to be at position 900 in YYY:
lseek(YYY, 900, 0); //Moves to position 900.
int WriteToYYY = write(YYY, ToBeInserted, sizeof(ToBeInserted));
if(WriteToYYY < 0)
  printf("Error upon writing to YYY");

//3.] Move to position 900 + length of ToBeInserted, and write the characters that were saved.
lseek(YYY, 926, 0);
int WriteMoreToYYY = write(YYY, EverythingPast900, sizeof(EverythingPast900));
if (WriteMoreToYYY < 0) {
  printf("Error writing the saved characters back into YYY.");
}
```

I think the logic is sound, mostly, although there are much better ways to do it in C.  I need help on my C pointers, basically, as well as the UNIX system calls.  Does anyone mind walking me through how to *properly* implement this in C?

Comment: In most cases you'd be better off just using a temporary file.

Answer (score 1):

That's the basic idea. If you had to really conserve RAM and the file was a lot bigger you'd want to copy block by block in reverse order. But the simpler way is to read the entire thing into memory and rewrite the entire file.

also, I prefer the stream functions: fopen, fseek, fread. But the file descriptor method works.

Comment: Mind going into detail on the copying by block in reverse order?  Not sure how I would go about that.  If the way that I wrote it isn't efficient, or just flat out sucks, that was kind of my overall question is how to make it better.

Comment: Is your file more than 100000 bytes? Then it might be worth it, but only on embedded machine. I'd still say just read to memory and rewrite. You probably want to read in 4K blocks that are aligned. Get the entire file size, determine the number of 4K blocks, copy all the blocks beyond your insert point, starting with the last. There is a lot of code involved so the easy way is just read into memory and be done with it.

Comment: only real problem with your way is it won't work on files less than 900 bytes long.

Comment: I really wanted to know how to do this with pointers, so I don't have to basically copy it to memory.  Isn't there a way to use pointers to move the end of file pointer 26 characters forward, and then the pointers at locations past 900 to location 926, 927, etc?

Comment: pointers are for memory, not for files. Yes, we call the fopen result a "file pointer" but that is not a C pointer. There is no way to just move data in a file without reading it into memory (short of a memory mapped file, which is operating system dependent).